# Trouble installing Siemens TIA software

Tags: plc, siemens, tia-portal

I've have installed the Siemens TIA software from [Siemens' Homepage](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/109753089/where-do-you-procure-the-current-trial-software-for-step-7-wincc-and-startdrive-for-tia-portal-v15-and-v15-1-?dti=0&lc=en-WW)

The version is: SIMATIC STEP 7 and WinCC V15.1 / S7-PLCSIM V15.1 TRIAL.

The error I get is:

```
An Error occurred during setup.  
Some installed products need licenses. Please start the Automation License  
Manager to install licenses and for an overview about licenses on this computer.
```

[image]

I tried running as administrator and changing the folder for the extracted files. I have full licenses to the TIA software.

Here is the setup report:

```
10:33:40 | BEGIN. Execution started.
10:33:49 | OK                        RunningProcesses           ()                          Complete
10:33:49 | OK                        InventoryBefore            (A)                         Complete
10:33:49 | OK                        Citamis                    (Before)                    Complete
10:34:08 | OK                        SecurityControlFeature     (ReturnFeatures)            Complete
10:34:08 | OK                        StartApplBefore            (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\SIEMENS.AUTOMATION.OBJECTFRAME.FILESTORAGE.SERVER.EXE)Complete
10:34:08 | OK                        StartApplBefore            (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]X64\BIN\SIEMENS.AUTOMATION.OBJECTFRAME.FILESTORAGE.SERVER.EXE)Complete
10:34:09 | OK                        ClassicCompPrepare         ()                          Complete
10:34:09 | OK                        ProductRegistration        (Before)                    Complete
10:34:09 | OK                        ClassicCompAfterUninstall  ()                          Complete
10:34:10 | OK                        SetupUnit                  (DotNet_Updater)            Complete  Foreign   AddLocal  
10:34:10 | OK                        Checkpoint                 (RE)                        Complete
10:34:13 | OK                        SetupUnit                  (SQLNCLI)                   Complete  Foreign   Reinstall
10:35:22 |ERROR    AdsWorkerClassicProduct::OnWorkerCompleted():  - ClassicProduct setup result: 30: Exit message:The specified directory, "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\", for the INSTALLSHAREDDIR parameter is not valid because this directory is compressed or is in a compressed directory. Specify a directory that is not compressed.
10:35:22 | FAIL!                     SetupUnit                  (INSTSQL2014EXP)            Failed    ClassicProductAddLocal  
10:35:22 | FAIL!                     Checkpoint                 (E)                         Complete
10:35:22 |ERROR    ExecutionEngine::StartNextStepAsync():  - Execution has been cancelled. Probably because of some process(es) running on the machine
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (CONFSQL2014EXP)            Skip      ClassicProductAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     Checkpoint                 (E)                         Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SYMLINK)                   Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SYMLINKADD)                Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCCORECOMP)               Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCCORECOMP64)             Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCNETAPI)                 Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCNETAPI45)               Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (NCMGPRS64)                 Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (NCMFWL64)                  Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPC)                       Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SECON)                     Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (S7DOS64)                   Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (S7DOS)                     Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (S7EDB)                     Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (Automation Software Updater)Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (TIA_Portal)                Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_Portal)                Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (TIA_Portal)                Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (MU_Client)                 Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HWCN-HWCOL)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEH02)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEH03)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEH04)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASETO01)               Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASETO02)               Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEWCF01)              Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIAP_SIMATIC)              Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIAP_SIMATIC32)            Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (STEP7)                     Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC Runtime Advanced Simulator)Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (PTSymLib)                  Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (PTTouchInput)              Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HM_AllEditions)            Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HM_NoBasic)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (UMC64)                     Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (UMC64)                     Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (UMC64)                     Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (LicenseManager)            Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (LicenseManager)            Skip      ClassicProductAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (LicenseManager)            Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (STOP_ALMSERVICE)           Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AlmPanelPlugin64)          Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (Prosave)                   Skip      ClassicProductAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_ES)                    Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_ES32)                  Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC_Tr_Mandatory)        Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC_TrC_All)             Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC_TrC_CAP)             Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (CoRtHmiRTmDriver64)        Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (HMIRTMV11)                 Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HMIRTMV11)                 Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (HMIRTMV11)                 Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (RT_Adv_Sim)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIACOMPCHECK)              Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (TIA_Opns)                  Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_Opns)                  Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (TIA_Opns)                  Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIAADMIN)                  Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AWB_SOFT)                  Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AWB_ALM)                   Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AWB_TIAUMAC)               Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (MUSERVER)                  Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     ClassicCompAfterInstall    ()                          Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     ClassicCompRollback        ()                          Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     HspInstall                 ()                          Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     MspInstall                 ()                          Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\INSTALLROOTCERTIFICATE.EXE)Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\SIEMENS.AUTOMATION.GENERATOR.FRAMEWORK.EXE)Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\S7EPATSX.EXE)Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\S7EPAESX.EXE)Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\SIEMENS.SIMATIC.HWCN.INTERPRETER.IG.GSD.GENERATOR.EXE)Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     ProductRegistration        (After)                     Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     InventoryAfter             (Z)                         Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     LicenseTransfer            (False)                     Skip
10:35:22 | SKIP!                     SetupReport                ()                          Skip
10:35:25 | OK                        SetupIsComplete            ()                          Complete
10:35:25 | OK                        Citamis                    (After)                     Complete
10:35:26 | OK                        SetupSummary               ()                          Complete
10:35:26 | END. Execution completed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\" folder has been compressed. Try right-clicking the folder and go to advanced and uncheck the "compress content" mark.

Comment: I've made a PasteBin with the setup report

Comment: Thanks you GlomB, this fixed the problem, i can now install the TIA without any complications