# Error to install Siemens TIA Portal v15/15.1/17

Tags: installation, plc, siemens, tia-portal

I'm trying to install Tia portal in any version mentioned in the title.

I have a Windows 11 pro 64 bit virtual machine with 12GB of RAM. Every time I start the installation after 5 seconds I get the following error "Some installed products require a license. Start Automation License for licensing or viewing the license summary on this PC."

Below the log file:

```
2023.03.13 22:23:46 - Year.Month.Day - Log start

BUNDLE: SIMATIC TIA Portal STEP 7 Professional V15 - WinCC Professional V15
SEBU Version: Professional:TIA.rgs.RTM_15000000:V15.00.00.00_26.01.00.01

OS: Microsoft Windows 11 Pro Professional, 64-bit, build 22621
COMMANDLINE: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Siemens\Automation\Siemens Installer Assistant\405\SIA2.exe /l1040 /starter /bundlepath=C:\USERS\CHRISTIAN\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\TIA PORTAL STEP 7 PROFESSIONAL WINCC PROFESSIONAL V15.0\InstData
INSTALLDIR: C:\Program Files\Siemens\Automation
SETUPLANGUAGE: 1040
PRODUCTLANGUAGES: 1033;1040

CHANGES: (+)MSMQ_Activation_Workstation;(+)DotNet_Updater;(+)INSTSQL2014EXP;(+)CONFSQL2014EXP;(+)INSTSQL2014EXP_SCADA;(+)SYMLINK;(+)SYMLINKADD;(+)SQLNCLI;(+)OPCCORECOMP;(+)OPCCORECOMP64;(+)OPCNETAPI;(+)OPCNETAPI45;(+)OPCUASDK;(+)OPCUALDS;(+)NCMGPRS64;(+)NCMFWL64;(+)WinCC ACE;(+)WinCC Common Archiving;(+)OPC;(+)Runtime Interfaces;(+)HMIProvider;(+)SECON;(+)S7DOS64;(+)S7DOS;(+)S7EDB;(+)Automation Software Updater;(+)TIA_Portal;(+)MU_Client;(+)HWCN-HWCOL;(+)SUPBASEH02;(+)SUPBASEH03;(+)SUPBASEH04;(+)SUPBASETO01;(+)SUPBASETO02;(+)SUPBASEWCF01;(+)TIAP_SIMATIC;(+)TIAP_SIMATIC32;(+)STEP7;(+)WinCC Runtime Advanced Simulator;(+)PTSymLib;(+)PTTouchInput;(+)HM_AllEditions;(+)HM_NoBasic;(+)STOBS;(+)UMC64;(+)LicenseManager;(+)STOP_ALMSERVICE;(+)AlmPanelPlugin64;(+)Prosave;(+)TIA_ES;(+)TIA_ES32;(+)WinCC_Tr_Mandatory;(+)WinCC_TrC_All;(+)WinCC_TrC_CAP;(+)SCADA-RT;(+)RT_Pro_Sim;(+)CoRtHmiRTmDriver64;(+)HMIRTMV11;(+)RT_Adv_Sim;(+)TIACOMPCHECK;(+)TIA_Opns;(+)OPCUA_Client;(+)TIAADMIN;(+)AWB_SOFT;(+)AWB_ALM;(+)AWB_TIAUMAC;(+)MUSERVER

There are NO severe messages before the installation


22:23:46 | BEGIN. Execution started.
22:23:48 | OK                        RunningProcesses           ()                          Complete
22:23:48 | OK                        InventoryBefore            (A)                         Complete
22:23:48 | OK                        Citamis                    (Before)                    Complete
22:23:54 | OK                        SecurityControlFeature     (ReturnFeatures)            Complete
22:23:54 | OK                        StartApplBefore            (TIAP15::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\SIEMENS.AUTOMATION.OBJECTFRAME.FILESTORAGE.SERVER.EXE)Complete
22:23:54 | OK                        StartApplBefore            (TIAP15::[INSTALLDIR]X64\BIN\SIEMENS.AUTOMATION.OBJECTFRAME.FILESTORAGE.SERVER.EXE)Complete
22:23:55 | OK                        ClassicCompPrepare         ()                          Complete
22:23:55 | OK                        ProductRegistration        (Before)                    Complete
22:23:55 | OK                        ClassicCompAfterUninstall  ()                          Complete
22:23:56 |ERROR    AdsWorkerForeignExe::GetInstallResult():  - -2146498548: assuming unknown error, because return value is not in OK-list which is only defined. Please check the corresponding log file for more detailed information
22:23:56 | FAIL!                     SetupUnit                  (MSMQ_Activation_Workstation)Failed    Foreign   AddLocal  
22:23:57 | OK                        SetupUnit                  (DotNet_Updater)            Complete  Foreign   AddLocal  
22:23:57 | FAIL!                     Checkpoint                 (RE)                        Complete
22:23:57 |ERROR    ExecutionEngine::StartNextStepAsync():  - Execution has been cancelled. Probably because of some process(es) running on the machine
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (INSTSQL2014EXP)            Skip      ClassicProductAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (CONFSQL2014EXP)            Skip      ClassicProductAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (INSTSQL2014EXP_SCADA)      Skip      ClassicProductAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SYMLINK)                   Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SYMLINKADD)                Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SQLNCLI)                   Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCCORECOMP)               Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCCORECOMP64)             Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCNETAPI)                 Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCNETAPI45)               Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCUASDK)                  Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCUALDS)                  Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (NCMGPRS64)                 Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (NCMFWL64)                  Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (WinCC ACE)                 Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC ACE)                 Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (WinCC ACE)                 Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC Common Archiving)    Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPC)                       Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (Runtime Interfaces)        Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HMIProvider)               Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SECON)                     Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (S7DOS64)                   Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (S7DOS)                     Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (S7EDB)                     Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (Automation Software Updater)Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (TIA_Portal)                Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_Portal)                Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (TIA_Portal)                Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (MU_Client)                 Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HWCN-HWCOL)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEH02)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEH03)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEH04)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASETO01)               Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASETO02)               Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEWCF01)              Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIAP_SIMATIC)              Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIAP_SIMATIC32)            Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (STEP7)                     Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC Runtime Advanced Simulator)Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (PTSymLib)                  Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (PTTouchInput)              Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HM_AllEditions)            Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HM_NoBasic)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (STOBS)                     Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (UMC64)                     Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (UMC64)                     Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (UMC64)                     Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (LicenseManager)            Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (LicenseManager)            Skip      ClassicProductAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (LicenseManager)            Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (STOP_ALMSERVICE)           Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AlmPanelPlugin64)          Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (Prosave)                   Skip      ClassicProductAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_ES)                    Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_ES32)                  Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC_Tr_Mandatory)        Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC_TrC_All)             Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC_TrC_CAP)             Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (SCADA-RT)                  Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SCADA-RT)                  Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (SCADA-RT)                  Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (RT_Pro_Sim)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (CoRtHmiRTmDriver64)        Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (HMIRTMV11)                 Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HMIRTMV11)                 Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (HMIRTMV11)                 Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (RT_Adv_Sim)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIACOMPCHECK)              Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (TIA_Opns)                  Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_Opns)                  Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (TIA_Opns)                  Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (OPCUA_Client)              Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCUA_Client)              Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (OPCUA_Client)              Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIAADMIN)                  Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AWB_SOFT)                  Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AWB_ALM)                   Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AWB_TIAUMAC)               Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (MUSERVER)                  Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     ClassicCompAfterInstall    ()                          Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     ClassicCompRollback        ()                          Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     HspInstall                 ()                          Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     MspInstall                 ()                          Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\INSTALLROOTCERTIFICATE.EXE)Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\SIEMENS.AUTOMATION.GENERATOR.FRAMEWORK.EXE)Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15::C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\S7EPATSX.EXE)Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15::C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\S7EPAESX.EXE)Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\SIEMENS.SIMATIC.HWCN.INTERPRETER.IG.GSD.GENERATOR.EXE)Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     ProductRegistration        (After)                     Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     InventoryAfter             (Z)                         Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     LicenseTransfer            (False)                     Skip
22:23:57 | SKIP!                     SetupReport                ()                          Skip
22:23:59 | OK                        SetupIsComplete            ()                          Complete
22:23:59 | OK                        Citamis                    (After)                     Complete
22:24:00 | OK                        SetupSummary               ()                          Complete
22:24:00 | END. Execution completed.

Intermediate ExitCode after execution queue: 1603
Errors: 2
Warnings: 0
```

I keep starting the installation with no success.

Comment: Please have a good look at this to see if you system is supported: [siemens](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/109758795/delivery-release-simatic-step-7-professional-basic-v15-1?dti=0&lc=en-NL) . And are sure you don't have any processes on the background like antivirius?

Comment: [This might too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020077/trouble-installing-siemens-tia-software) | [This might need to be enabled](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21245) And run it as adminstrator.

Comment: I'm sure everything is fine, only once managed to go ahead with the installation. The problem is that it started easily but without the libraries, so I couldn't add hardware etc.
I had to forcefully uninstall the program and reinstall it but always with negative results.. and always with the same error.
The antivirus is disabled completely.

Comment: is this a clean installation of windows or did you install it over an old version of tia portal. If so you either need to reinstall your windows or do a lot of manual repairing

Comment: I already tried to install it on a new virgin virtual machine to rule out the problem of dirt of any kind. The error remains. I repeat that unfortunately I was able to install it only once and it worked perfectly, but without the libraries... absurd.

Comment: my best guess is install a windows version that is recommended: [siemens](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/109758795/delivery-release-simatic-step-7-professional-basic-v15-1?dti=0&lc=en-CN)

Comment: I thought about it too, but tia portal v17 also has windows 11 as a supported operating system, but it doesn't work either

Comment: Can you verify that Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) Server is enabled in Controlpanel - Programs and Features -  Turn Windows features on or off

Comment: Just wait i will back to home and i’ll verify it

Comment: I tried to install MSMQ but it doesn't work anyway...